# C# HttpClient, getting error Cannot add value because header 'content-type' does not support multiple values

Tags: c#

```
HttpClient serviceClient = new HttpClient();
serviceClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept", "Application/JSON");

HttpContent content = new StringContent(text);
content.Headers.Add("content-type", "text/html");

var response = await serviceClient.PostAsync(new Uri(_serviceUrl), content);
```

This is my code. I want to do a POST, and set the content type to text/html, but when I do this I get the above error.

I can set the content type it seems via `content.Headers.ContentType` but I don't know how to specifcy "text/html" if I do that. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Haven't got .NET 4.5 ready, but according to [`HttpContentHeaders.ContentType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.httpcontentheaders.contenttype.aspx) and [`MediaTypeHeaderValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.mediatypeheadervalue.aspx), it should look something like this:

```
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
```

Comment: `content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html")` was accepted, perhaps that's it. Its parameter is `string mediaType`.

Comment: @SLC so it should be `content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html")`?

Comment: I believe so, it doesn't error, but who knows if it's sending the right headers. Usually the content type includes the character encoding too, but appending that generates an error so I am ignoring it for now...

Answer (score 5):

This error implies that you try to add an header that has already been added to the `DefaultRequestHeaders` (not only `content-type` header, but any other header that do not support multiple values).

---

In my case, I was initiating the headers from two different places and accidentally added the same key header twice (for example `content-type` or `Authentication`).

Inside the `startup.cs`, `IHttpClientFactory` ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2)) like:

```
services.AddHttpClient("MyHttpClient", client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.google.co.il/");
    client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("content-type", "application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "some values"));
});
```

And got updated inside the client service:

```
HttpClient httpClient = this._httpClientFactory.CreateClient("MyHttpClient");    
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("content-type", "application/json")); //Throws Exception!
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "some values")); //Throws Exception!
```

---

UPDATE:
In cases you want to be sure that you can add header you can use carefully the `DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear()`

Answer (score 5):

As soon as you assign a text value to the HttpContent by doing this-

```
HttpContent content = new StringContent(text);
```

the content type is automatically set for that content. This content type (in case of String Content) is - `{text/plain; charset=utf-8}`

So in the next step when you try to explicitly set the Content-Type header you get the error- *Cannot add value because header 'Content-Type' does not support multiple values.*

There are three ways by which you can set the content type and avoid this error:

**Option 1.** Specify the content type while setting the content

```
HttpContent content = new StringContent(text, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "text/html");
```

**Option 2.** Setting the ContentType property

```
HttpContent content = new StringContent(text);    
content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
```

**Option 3.** First remove the automatically assigned content-type header and then add that header again.

```
HttpContent content = new StringContent(text);  
content.Headers.Remove("content-type");  
content.Headers.Add("content-type", "text/html");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            DateFormatHandling =
                DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat
        };
        var serializedString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, settings);

        var conent = new StringContent(serializedString);
        conent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        var response = await this.httpClient.PostAsync(requestUri, conent).ConfigureAwait(false);

        T requestResult = default(T);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            requestResult = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
        }
```

Comment: please add some explanation to your answer, showing what the code does and how it solves the problem. This will help others in the future

Comment: response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); throws an exception if the request fails, so there is no sense in checking response.IsSuccessStatusCode.