# Does Kestrel need UseHttps when making a request to an HTTPS endpoit?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, https

I have Kestrel configured behind a reverse proxy (Nginx). I'm trying to consume an endpoint (which is HTTPS) and I keep getting:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Invalid request line.

After a while of searching the internet I've seen people suggesting it's because I'm hitting an HTTP endpoint from an HTTPS endpoint, but, in my case, I'm hitting an HTTPS endpoint from an HTTP and not very sure how to go about this. I'm doing the request following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.1) with a some modifications:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new{ FieldA = "A", FieldB = "B" });
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "/api/some-endpoint")
{
    Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8)
};
request.Content.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.ContentType, MediaTypeNames.Application.Json);

var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("my-client");
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

var myResp = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<MyResponse>();
```

I'm registering the `IHttpClientFactory` in the following way:

```
services.AddHttpClient("my-client", (sp, c) =>
{
    var opts = sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MyOptions>>().Value;
    var uriB = new UriBuilder
    {
        Host = opts.Host,
        Port = opts.Port,
        Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps
    };
    c.BaseAddress = uriB.Uri;
});
```

I would prefer not to have to configure Kestrel to `UseHttps` just for this 'cause I have Nginx taking care of HTTPS from the outside world into my app. Is there something I can do instead of that (assuming that solves the error)?

**UPDATE**: I'm targeting version .Net Core 2.1 and I'm using the forwarded headers middleware in the following way:

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedHost
});
```

It's also the first middleware I use in my `Startup.Configure` method. My Nginx location is configured as:

```
location /api {
    proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

Comment: Which version of ASP.NET Core? Do you call `UseForwardedHeaders`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-3.0 iirc in some versions there was some constraint that `UseForwardedHeader`wasn't called implicitly with `UseIISIntegration` (which wasn't called on Linux). As long as you use `UseForwardedHeaders` with the correct header names and your reverse proxy sends these ASP.nET Core will recognize it as Https and not do an https redirect. Also avoid using `UseHttpsRedirection`

Comment: @Tseng I edited my question. I'm seeing that I'm using `app.UseHttpsRedirection()`, I'll remove that and trying again. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the way I was constructing the request. I followed @Tseng recommendations but I kept getting the error, I even explicitly changed forwarded headers name to match those set in my Nginx configuration (just in case) with no luck. This is how I made it to work:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new{ FieldA = "A", FieldB = "B" });
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "/api/some-endpoint")
{
    Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8)
};
//Changed this line. I think the previous line was the problem 'cause 
// I saw a header duplication error in the stack trace referring to
// the content type header, so overriding the header may have 
// made the error gone
request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json);

var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("my-client");
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

var myResp = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<MyResponse>();
```

And updated my `IHttpClientFactory` configuration as:

```
services.AddHttpClient("my-client", (sp, c) =>
{
    var opts = sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MyOptions>>().Value;
    var uriB = new UriBuilder
    {
        Host = opts.Host,
        Port = opts.Port,
        Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps
    };
    c.BaseAddress = uriB.Uri;
    // Added this line
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(HeaderNames.Accept, MediaTypeNames.Application.Json);
});
```

[This](http://[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337256/c-sharp-httpclient-getting-error-cannot-add-value-because-header-content-type)) post helped in the changes I made. Hope this help somebody in the future.